# Unable to getState() from a Google motion chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, closures

I'm trying to get the state of a Google Motion Chart so that I can modify the Initial State in the chart options. The documentation suggests creating a button that will call getState() on the chart to retrieve the string with the parameters that you want.

However, calling getState() on chart returns "null" when I try console.log() the value from inside the drawChart function and won't work at all when I try to call it from a button using a closure. Here's my code:

```
<script>

function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  //there is data here
  data.addRows(datajson);

  var options = {};
  //there are options here

  var chart = new google.visualization.MotionChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);

  var getChartState = function() {
    var chartState = chart.getState();
    console.log(chartState);
  };

  return getChartState;

};

</script>

<div onclick="getChartState()">Get Chart State</div>
<div id="chart_div">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible that this `console.log(charState);` should have been `console.log(chartState);`?

Comment: @Dan no, sorry, that was just a transcription error. The typo wasn't in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Motion Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/motionchart) is a **Flash** based component, you are probably getting null from `getState` function since the chart could not be rendered properly which in turn could be related with the following reasons:

- Ensure Flash Player is installed on your computer, follow [this
  link](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html) to determine whether Flash Player in installed at your
  system
- Because of Flash security settings, [Motion Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/motionchart) (and all Flash-based
  visualizations) might not work correctly when accessed from a file
  location in the browser (e.g., `file:///c:/webhost/myhost/myviz.html`)
  rather than from a web server URL

**[Working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/cjX3fn5lYafKiifA5RHu?p=preview)** that demonstrates how to draw [Motion Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/motionchart) and get it's state.

Comment: The chart renders fine, but calling getState() on chart still returns null. Also, the working example doesn't show getState() in action on the chart.